# SolrCloud - core swap and Zookeeper distribution in Sitecore solution

Tags: solr, sitecore, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

Recently I came across a very stange behaviour of Zookeeper looking after Solr setup.

**In details:**

Sitecore allows for SOLR core switch on full index rebuild. This feature is very handy, when one decides for rebuiding index data from scratch. Although, when SOLR is set up with Zookeeper, only leader's core is swapped. The second server still points to old core folder, but the data are updated as required. In result, both servers point to different cores and produce different search results.

**Question:**
Is there any option in either Zookeeper or Solr to help distibute the core switch across all SOLR nodes ?

Any tips would be very welcome,

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question, will follow this one!

Comment: Have you looked at - https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.449298 ?